# How to insert random number into database no repeat

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I Have a registration, where for every person who registers gets a unique user id. this user id should not be repeating so that each person has a unique id. The user id is then inserted into 2 different tables. But every time a new person registers the number for user id in the database is always returning 0.

here's my code:

```
    $userid = '';
function randomDigits($length){
$numbers = range(0,10000000);
shuffle($numbers);
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
    global $digits;
    $userid .= $numbers[$i];
}
return $userid;
}

    $query = "INSERT INTO Users (user_id, user_type, name, lastname, email, phone, address, apt, city, state, zip, username, password) VALUES ('$userid','parent','$name', '$lastname', '$email', '$phone', '$address', '$apt', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$username', '$hash')";
    $result = mysqli_query($query);


    $sql = "INSERT INTO dancers (user_id, name, dancer_name, dancer_middlename, dancer_lastname, dancer_age, dancer_dob, dancer_number, school_code, teacher_name, class_location, date_enrolled, date_comp) VALUES ('$userid', '$name', '$dancer_name', '$dancer_middlename', '$dancer_lastname', '$dancer_age', '$dancer_dob', '$dancer_number', '$schoolcode', '$teacher', '$location', '$date_enrolled', '$date_comp')";


     $result2 = mysqli_query($sql);
     if(!$result = $con->query($query)){
         die('there was an error running query [' . $con->error . ']');
     }else {
       //  header("location: thankyou.html");
     }
    if(!$result2 = $con->query($sql)){
         die('there was an error running query [' . $con->error . ']');
     }else {
         header("location: thankyou.html");
     }
    }
```

**EDIT**

Initially I did use auto increment, but this wasn't working for me. The issue is that, yes it auto increments for the Users table, but I need the SAME user-id from the Users table to also be inserted in the Dancers table.

The dancers table needs to have it's own unique id as well as the user-id. This is important because users are able to delete dancers and their page, so in the invent that someone is deleted auto-increment does not work.
So originally when I used auto increment for the users this it how it would insert, while 3 was deleted.

**USERS TABLE**

```
user-id |   user-type   |   name   |  etc   |

1       |   parent      |  Ashley  | etc    |

2       |   parent      |  Liz     | etc    |

4       |   parent      |  Chris   | etc    |
```

**DANCERS TABLE**

```
id   |   user-id   | name   |  dancer name   |

1    |     0       | Ashley |     Ben        |

2    |     0       | Liz    |     Tom        |

3    |     0       | Chris  |     Meg        |
```

But this is what it should be:

**USERS TABLE**

```
user-id |   user-type   |   name   |  etc   |

1       |   parent      |  Ashley  | etc    |

2       |   parent      |  Liz     | etc    |

4       |   parent      |  Chris   | etc    |
```

**DANCERS TABLE**

```
id   |   user-id   | name   |  dancer name   |

1    |     1       | Ashley |     Ben        |

2    |     2       | Liz    |     Tom        |

3    |     4       | Chris  |     Meg        |
```

**EDIT 2 WITH ANSWER**

I used approached D in the answer given by Damián Pablo González.

Here is the correct code:

```
$userId = rand(1,9999999);
$check_userId ="select count(*) count from Users where user_id = " . 
$userId;
while ($row['count'] > 0);

$query = "INSERT INTO Users (user_id, user_type, name, lastname, email, phone, address, apt, city, state, zip, username, password) VALUES ('$userid','parent','$name', '$lastname', '$email', '$phone', '$address', '$apt', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$username', '$hash')";
    $result = mysqli_query($query);


    $sql = "INSERT INTO dancers (user_id, name, dancer_name, dancer_middlename, dancer_lastname, dancer_age, dancer_dob, dancer_number, school_code, teacher_name, class_location, date_enrolled, date_comp) VALUES ('$userid', '$name', '$dancer_name', '$dancer_middlename', '$dancer_lastname', '$dancer_age', '$dancer_dob', '$dancer_number', '$schoolcode', '$teacher', '$location', '$date_enrolled', '$date_comp')";


     $result2 = mysqli_query($sql);
     if(!$result = $con->query($query)){
         die('there was an error running query [' . $con->error . ']');
     }else {
       //  header("location: thankyou.html");
     }
    if(!$result2 = $con->query($sql)){
         die('there was an error running query [' . $con->error . ']');
     }else {
         header("location: thankyou.html");
     }
    }
```

Comment: why not use auto-increment id?

Comment: Please see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Approach A

(Best in my opinion) As Wreigh suggested, it's better to use an auto-increment field, it covers it all for you, so you don't have to worry about this things.

For this, try this MySQL command. `ALTER TABLE Users MODIFY COLUMN user_id INT auto_increment`. After that, you can just insert the other fields and user_id will always be unique:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Users (user_type, name, lastname, email, phone, address, apt, city, state, zip, username, password) VALUES ('parent','$name', '$lastname', '$email', '$phone', '$address', '$apt', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$username', '$hash')";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
```

### **Approach B**:

inserting the next id available:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Users (user_id, user_type, name, lastname, email, phone, address, apt, city, state, zip, username, password) SELECT max(user_id)+1,'parent','$name', '$lastname', '$email', '$phone', '$address', '$apt', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$username', '$hash' from Users";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
```

Look what I did: I used `INSERT (fields) SELECT`, without `VALUES`. That will insert the id at the same time it reads. This requires user_id to be numeric.

### **Approach C**

(as I saw you use quotes for user_id, maybe it's a string field)

1) If user_id is string, generate an very-likely unique id using [uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

> Gets a prefixed unique identifier based on the current time in microseconds.

2) Then, just to be sure, check if it's not used.

```
do {
    $uniq = uniqid();
    $query ="select count(*) count from Users where user_id = '" . $uniq ."'";
    //execute and do a fetch 
} while ($row['count'] > 0);
```

It will keep trying until id is really unique. This requires user_id to be string field, like varchar, since uniqid() returns letters AND numbers.

### **Approach D**

(similar to C but numeric)

1) If user_id is integer, generate an very-likely unique id using [rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php)

> rand — Generate a random integer

2) Then, just to be sure, check if it's not used.

```
do {
    $uniq = rand(1,999999);
    $query ="select count(*) count from Users where user_id = " . $uniq;
    //execute and do a fetch 
} while ($row['count'] > 0);
```

It will ke

Comment: Approach A didn't work for me because of the reason I mentioned in my edited question. Approach B didn't work for the same reason as approach A. Since the id is an integer I went with approach D and it worked perfectly for me. So I assume approach C would also work well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For unique random number you can use below function.You can pass length as you want.

```
    public static function generateUniqueId($length = 7) {
        $salt = "abcdefghijkmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ23456789";
        srand(); // start the random generator
        $userId = ""; // set the inital variable
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) { // loop and create userId
            $userId .= substr($salt, rand() % strlen($salt), 1);
        }
        return $userId;
    }
```